# Send headers through generic method on HTTP CRUD workflow

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular7, ionic4

I have a service like this:

*Note:* Here I need to work with the `cookies`

```
  book(data: Spa): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(`${environment.apiURL}:${environment.port}/${environment.domain}/abc/my.json`, data,
      {
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
      });
  }
```

You can see that each and every method where I have to send `headers`. Which is very ugly and not `DRY`. So I would like to write generic `CRUD` to add it automatically. How can I do that?

I have tried this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CommonService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  post(url, params): Observable<any> {
    return new Observable(observer => {
      const headers = new Headers();
      let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.createHeader(headers) });
      this.http.post(url, params, options)
        .subscribe(response => {
          observer.next(response);
          observer.complete();
        }, (e) => {
          observer.error(e);
        });

    })
  }

  createHeader(headers: Headers): Headers {
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    return headers;
  }
}
```

But it gives this `compile time` error on this line `let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.createHeader(headers) });`

> Type 'Headers' is missing the following properties from type
>   'Headers': keys, values, toJSON, getAll, and 2 more.ts(2740)
>   interfaces.d.ts(61, 5): The expected type comes from property
>   'headers' which is declared here on type 'RequestOptionsArgs'
>   (property) RequestOptionsArgs.headers?: Headers

And it says this `warning` too:

> RequestOptions is deprecated: see https://angular.io/guide/http
>   (deprecation)

Comment: You are mixing 2 different APIs: Http and HttpClient. Stick to the latest.

Comment: I did that since `RequestOptions` is not in `@angular/common/http`. Any better example?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
this.http.post(url, params, {headers: this.createHeader(headers)})
```

or even better, have a look at [HttpInterceptors](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor) for generic headers

and here a nice little [tutorial](https://scotch.io/@vigneshsithirai/angular-6-7-http-client-interceptor-with-error-handling)